# YCSB is not working for HBase

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, ycsb

I am using **hadoop-2.7.1**,**hbase-1.0.1.1**, and **zookeeper-3.4.6** on my linux server to compare HBase performance. My Hadoop, HBase, ZooKeeper are working fine with the below process:

19639 DataNode

19893 SecondaryNameNode

20116 ResourceManager

20530 QuorumPeerMain

20287 NodeManager

23767 Client

20838 HMaster

21015 HRegionServer

24620 Jps

19446 NameNode

In addition, YCSB also working fine. I have checked with BasicDb command '*./bin/ycsb load basic -P workloads/workloada*'. However, while I am trying to run for the HBase with the simplest command '*./bin/ycsb load hbase -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=family*'. It is not responding at all. I don't know why I'm having this problem. Could you please help me out problem this problem? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved the problem. *conf/hbase-site.xml* had problem, it wasn't getting right Zookeeper clientport. Default **2181** is much better to use.